Unexpected UI of Flutter and layout

Here is the detail of my problem I want the text to appear right below the thumb icon but it does not happen.
If I use stack with Positioned widget then the 2 below icons are not
clickable even though IconButton have its own onPressed method.
The space is too much between the thumb icon, text and also comment icon. Please check the image.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : PageView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                List<dynamic> likesList = quoteList[index]['likes'];
                int quote_id = quoteList[index]['id'];

                detectId = isIdPresent(quote_id, likesList); //true
                bool likeUnlikeDetectId = detectId;
                print(detectId);

                String getCleanQuote() {
                  // Remove HTML tags and entities from the quote text
                  RegExp exp = RegExp(r"<[^>]*>|&[^;]+;",
                      multiLine: true, caseSensitive: true);
                  return quoteList[index]['qoute'].replaceAll(exp, '');
                }

                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        // widget.quote,
                        // quoteList[index]['qoute'],
                        getCleanQuote(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.68,
                      // left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.81,
                      right: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            // screen aa rhai hain abb??
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                detectId = !detectId; // Toggle the local state
                                if (detectId) {
                                  likesList.add({
                                    'qoute_id':
                                        quoteList[index]['id'].toString()
                                  });
                                } else {
                                  likesList.removeWhere((item) =>
                                      item['qoute_id'] ==
                                      quoteList[index]['id'].toString());
                                }
                              });

                              likeUnlikeDetectId
                                  ? handleLikeOrUnlike(
                                      quoteList[index]['id'], 'unlike', context)
                                  : handleLikeOrUnlike(
                                      quoteList[index]['id'], 'like', context);
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                                likeUnlikeDetectId
                                    ? Icons.thumb_up
                                    : Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined,
                                color: likeUnlikeDetectId
                                    ? Colors.blueAccent
                                    : Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          Text(likesList.length.toString()),
                          LikeButton(
                            size: 30.0,
                            // isLiked: isFavourite,
                            // likeCount: favouriteCounter,
                            countPostion: CountPostion.bottom,
                            countBuilder: (count, isLiked, text) {
                              return Text(
                                text,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: isLiked ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return commentSection();
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.comment,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('23.9k'),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              print('click the report..!');
                              openReportModel();
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.circleExclamation,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      // child: Stack(
                      //   children: <Widget>[

                      //     // const Positioned(
                      //     //   top: 35,
                      //     //   left: 20.0,
                      //     //   bottom: 0.0,
                      //     //   child: Text('1'),
                      //     // )
                      //   ],
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }

I want to appear text below the thumb icon also comment icon but its space is too mush you can view in the picture above if I used the Stack and through the Positioned widget then after two icons
are not onPresseable

Why are you using stack if it is achievable through columns? Add the main column as your parent instead of the stack and in their children add multiple columns and give them crossAxisAligment at end. Don't use position if this is achievable through align then please add that widget instead of position.

The space between the thumb icon and the text '1' below it is due to the padding around the icon. In IconButton, there's a clickable circle area around the icon that appears when you click the icon. If you want to reduce this padding, you can adjust the padding around the icon using the padding property. Simply set it to zero if you don't want any padding. Additionally, you can explore the constraints property for further customization options.
IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
)

setting this will remove the padding b/w the thumb icon and text
You can rewrite the provided statement as follows:
If you can handle debouncing on your own, feel free to use GestureDetector instead of using a IconButton. GestureDetector doesn't provide debouncing like buttons do, but you can implement debouncing manually if needed."
